# Threading Timer to connect to database(Entity Framework) at specified interval C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, timer

I have a threading timer(windows service) which connects to a database to read values from a specified table(via Entity Framework) every 30 seconds and update other table values
based on some condition.

sorry i forgot to place the source code

```
var timeInterval = config.GetConfigValue(Constants.SpecifiedTimeInterval); // reading from config file

var timeDuration = config.GetConfigValue(Constants.SpecifiedTimeElapsed); //reading from config file

TimerCallback cb= new TimerCallback(TimerElapsed);
Timer timerForDatabasePolling = new Timer(cb, null, Convert.ToInt32(timeInterval), System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

private static void TimerElapsed(object obj)
{
    //connecting to
}
```

Would you like to know feedback on the approach as i am newbie to threading

Comment: Please show us your code so far and explain the issue thoroughly so we can help you to solve whatever issue you are having with it.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  The only thing here is stating what you have.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: That's awesome. I also have a cat.

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach is sound, but you have a bit of a problem.

You're passing `Timeout.Infinite` as the last parameter, which will make your timer a one-shot. That is, it will wait `timeInterval` milliseconds before it fires once, and then it will never fire again. If you want it to fire every 30 seconds, you can pass `timeInterval` as the last parameter, but then if your processing takes longer than 30 seconds the timer will fire again and you have multiple callbacks executing concurrently. That's usually a bad thing.

What you want to do is initialize the timer as a one-shot and then have the callback re-initialize it. So you'd have:

```
Timer timerForDatabasePolling = new Timer(
    cb, 
    null,
    Convert.ToInt32(timeInterval)
    Timeout.Infinite);
```

And in your callback:

```
private static void TimerElapsed(object obj)
{
    // Do all the stuff you need to do here.

    // When you're done, reset the timer
    timerForDatabasePolling.Change(timeInterval, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

That ensures that you don't get multiple concurrent callbacks. The next callback will occur 30 seconds after the previous callback completes.